# object inside of props (general props/javascript question)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just a bit of confusion over this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
// Get all homes
const homes = await prisma.home.findMany();
// Pass the data to the Home page
return {
props: {
homes: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(homes)),
},
};
}

  export default function Home({ homes = [] }) {
  return (
  <div>
  <h1 className="text-xl font-medium text-gray-800">
  Top-rated places to stay
  </h1>
  <p className="he">
  Explore some of the best places in the world
  </p>
  <div className="mt-8">
  <div>{homes} </div>
  </div>
  </div>    
  );
```

It works but I would have assumed that to access homes , you have to do homes.homes
because homes is an object or property inside of props
the props are passed to the function as 'homes' so if the props are named 'homes' then shouldnt the actual homes array be a property of that?
Hence
homes.homes
can someone please explain why its not the case?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`?

Comment: It was example code, not sure why they did that!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter for a functional component is *the whole props object*. This props object is the same one that is on the right side of `props:` in `getServerSideProps`.

It might be easier to visualize without the destructuring, and by declaring an extra variable for the `props` object in `getServerSideProps`. The below code is equivalent to your current code.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Get all homes
    const homes = await prisma.home.findMany();
    // Pass the data to the Home page
    const props = { homes: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(homes)) }
    return {
        props: props,
    };
}
```

```
export default function Home(props) {
  const homes = props.homes ?? [];
  // ...
```

Above the `const props` in `getServerSideProps` is the exact same object as the `props` argument in `Home`. It has one property, `homes`, which could be called "a prop". That property looks to be an array taken from `JSON.parse`.